# open() system call polymorphism

Tags: c, system-calls

I just discovered that the open() (man 2 open) system call has two versions:

```
   int open(const char *pathname, int flags);
   int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);
```

And indeed, one can use either in a single C file and both would work. How can standard C achieve this?

Comment: @ZhangYuan In C? Not at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In fact, it's not C++-style function overloading. It's just that `open()` is variadic:

```
int open(const char *fname, int flags, ...);
```

And only if "flags" require it, will it look for the third argument.

Comment: didn't see any relationship between flags and mode in the man page. Care to elaborate?

Comment: @lang2 the mode is *only used if required,* for example, when `O_CREAT` is specified as flag. There's no sense in talking about the file mode when, for example, you open a file for reading...

Answer (score 5):

It can be done as a variable argument function.

The POSIX documentation for [`open`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) specifies it like this:

```
int open(const char *path, int oflag, ...);
```